# Is there an easier way to make a JPQL query with BETWEEN to include NULL values in properties

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have a JPQL query

```
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE :chosenDate BETWEEN e.periodFrom AND e.periodTo")
    List<Entry> findByChosenDate(LocalDate chosenDate);
```

There is a problem, that when one of the properties "periodFrom" or "periodTo" aren't set the entry won't be selected. I want that the query also include entires with one or two NULL values.

I want that the query select entries in three additional cases:

1. When "periodFrom" is null and "periodTo" is null the entry should be found.
2. When "periodFrom" is null and "periodTo" >=:chosenDate the entry should be found.
3. When "periodFrom" <= :chosenDate and "periodTo" is null the entry should be found.

Is there an easier way to make such a query than :

```
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE (:chosenDate BETWEEN e.periodFrom AND e.periodTo) 
        OR (e.periodFrom IS NULL AND e.periodTo IS NULL )
        OR ( e.periodFrom <= :chosenDate AND e.periodTo IS NULL)
        OR (e.periodFrom IS NULL AND e.periodTo >= :chosenDate)") 
    List<Entry> findByChosenDate(LocalDate chosenDate);
```

Comment: Have you considered supplying some default values to the query so that it never deals with NULL values directly? `COALESCE` the dates to some sensible default so that they still satisfy your criteria

Comment: I haven't considered supplying default values but i will think about it. Yes, using COALESCE makes the query shorter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if you find it better, but something like this would be shorter:

```
SELECT e FROM Entry e WHERE (:chosenDate BETWEEN COALESCE(e.periodFrom, 0000-01-01) AND COALESCE(e.periodTo, 9999-12-31)
```

Comment: Depending on the db, you may need to use `0001-01-01` for date lower bound.